# Liferay 7 Portal community (latest) REST API call delay

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I've a delay about 1000 ms on every call to Liferay 7 Portal API. For example in Postman: https://ibb.co/vhnZrJp

It is the same result in my Remote App (JS, fetch loop or Promise.all()). And the same with Docker image of Liferay.

So, how to improve it? Or it's because of our server? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Otherwise: Hard to say from a distance. I've seen slowness with logging that was attempting a DNS lookup of the client IP, but it could be anything else. Please measure where your application spends the time: CPU? Database? Network? Is your server relatively idle or under high load? If you attempt to orovide a full [mcve], there's a good chance you'll step into the issue yourself while creating it.

Comment: ok, general rules to find the answer... So, if a Docker image shows the same delay I'll  try to realize using it.

Comment: There's still no solution. We checked it on different servers and even on my mac Pro I getting the same result 900-1000 ms for http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/organization/get-organizations?companyId=20097&parentOrganizationId=0 request.. https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/installation-and-upgrades/setting-up-liferay/tuning-liferay.html and https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/installation-and-upgrades/setting-up-liferay/tuning-your-jvm.html didn't help.

Comment: Different DB don't play a role. Java 8 or 11 too. I think the issue hidden in Tomcat. But we are not experts in it. May be somebody will want to check my issue and confirm it. And then Liferay team will check it to and help us to find the solution.